# nodeJS - modify HTML file to display images

Tags: html, node.js, web

I have a static HTML page, and I am using NodeJS to serve that page.

I want to be able to give the HTML page URLS of images dynamically from NodeJS so that those images can be displayed.

How would I do this?

Comment: Convert the HTML to a template such as EJS/Pug/Mustache. EJS would be most appropriate since it's basically HTML with variables. So you only need to rename e.g. index.html to index.ejs and replace the image URLs with variables.

Comment: Did my answer help? Or did you run into an issue implementing it that way?

Answer (score 2):

Use a templating engine of some sort. An easy view template engine to start with is called [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). This will allow you to dynamically create "layouts" for the bulk of the html page that stays the same, while at the same time allow you to create "views" which are the partial html files that will be inserted to the layout. An example of this would be a header and a footer. The header and footer will most likely stay the same throughout your website so you would put that in your layout file and inside of the body is where the dynamic views can be rendered.

Handlebars uses this notation to render httpRequest data inside of your html file:

**html**

```
<div id='user-profile-image'> {{profile_image_uri}} </div>
```

**js**

```
app.get('/user-by-name', function(req, res) {

    var options =
    {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "url" : "blah.com"
    }

    // Using the request module
    request.get(options, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err)
            return
        }
        // First param is your view name
        // Second param is your json response body which is rendered in 
        // the view using handlebars {{}}
        res.render('your_view_name_here', JSON.parse(body)) 
    }
}
```